# Software for sharing files and printers among different computers in a WiFi network

Tags: windows, file-management, networking, sharing, printing

I am looking for a software that allows people to share files and printers and also other devices among different computers within a WiFi network.

I have a PC which uses Windows 7, a laptop which has Windows 8 and another one which uses Windows 10. The software should allow the transfer of files between all these devices.

I have a printer attached to the PC. So it should be able to print from any of the computers. All the above mentioned computers are connected to a WiFi network.

It would be a plus if it is also possible to share files to any of these computers from Android devices.

So in short: a complete file and device sharing platform for all kinds of devices connected to a wireless network.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking at doing is setting up a windows **home group** - which is the MS Windows mechanism for sharing information, printers, etc., amongst computers on the same network.

Unfortunately, while Windows machines from 7 onwards can all be connected to the same "home group" the mechanism for setting up & joining one differs between versions.

Instructions for [Windows 7 & Windows 8.1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/homegroup-help#homegroup-start-to-finish=windows-7&v1h=win81tab1&v2h=win7tab1) and the same page will tell you they have moved the information for Windows 10 **but not where to** however [this post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/homegroup-win10-not-recognize-printer-scanner-on/dd16c658-2fdd-45b2-a032-f2bc9691b8b2?auth=1) is helpful. Homegroup setup can be found by following the respective links, but basically you need to set up your home group on one machine and then join from the others. You can then pick what to share.